# Most efficient way to iterate rows across 2 dataframes checking for a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So I have a dataframe (D1) that looks like this:

| nID | name |
| --- | --- |
| n1 | Sarah |
| n2 | John |

and I have another dataframe (D2) which looks like

| tID | writers | directors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | n1,n4 | n2,n3 |
| t2 | n4 | n3 |
| t3 | n1 | n2. |

The nID in D1 can be in either writers or directors column in D2. Now for each nID, I want to get all the tID where the nID is in either of the columns and store the list of tID in a new column in D1.

So the final D1 would looks like this:

| nID | name. | tIdS. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | Sara | t1,t3 |
| n2 | John | t1,t3 |

What's the most efficient way to do this using Pandas, as I have about 30k rows in D1 and 800k rows in D2? Is it better to split the column into multiple columns and do a merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can do `explode` then `melt` + `groupby` with the nId in `df2` get the tID

```
df2['writers'] = df2['writers'].str.split(',')
df2['directors'] = df2['directors'].str.split(',')
s = df2.melt('tID').explode('value').groupby('value')['tID'].agg(','.join)
df1['new'] = df1['nID'].map(s)
df1
Out[221]: 
  nID   name    new
0  n1  Sarah  t1,t3
1  n2   John  t1,t3
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thanks! Can you explain what's happening in the explode and the groupby process?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is a way to do this:

```py
d1.merge(
    d2.assign(nID=(d2['writers'] + d2['directors']).apply(set))
    .explode('nID').groupby('nID')['tID'].agg(set),
    on='nID', how='left')
```

This is assuming the columns 'writers' and 'directors' are already type `list`.

Speed:

```py
np.random.seed(0)

n1 = 3_000
n2 = 80_000
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'nID': np.arange(n1),
    'name': [f'name_{i:06d}' for i in range(n1)],
})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'tID': np.arange(n2),
    'writers': [
        list(np.random.choice(d1.nID, k, replace=False))
        for k in np.random.randint(1, min(4, n1)+1, n2)
    ],
    'directors': [
        list(np.random.choice(d1.nID, k, replace=False))
        for k in np.random.randint(1, min(4, n1)+1, n2)
    ]
})

%timeit d1.merge(d2.assign(nID=(d2['writers'] + d2['directors']).apply(set)).explode('nID').groupby('nID')['tID'].agg(set), on='nID', how='left')
384 ms ± 697 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the loops would be 3_000 * 80_000?

Comment: That was just to generate some DataFrames for timing - 3K rows for `d1` and 80K for `d2`. The generation process is not optimized at all and much slower than the answer itself, which takes 384ms on my machine.